# express上（express-generator）でファイルのアップロードができません

Tags: express.js

以下のサイトを見ながらexpress上でexpress-form-dataを使用してファイルのアップロードを実装しました。

[Express.js ファイルアップロード (express-form-data 編)](https://qiita.com/tadnakam/items/4f7af58af86cf60bf0e8)

しかし、実行結果（router.jsのconsole.logの結果）のように何も表示されずファイルの受け渡しができていません。
どのようにすればファイルのアップロードをできるようになるか教えてほしいです。

実行結果
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

ディレクトリ構成
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

ソースコード
app.js

```
var functions = require('firebase-functions');
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');
var admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();
var app = express();


// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('admin', admin.firestore().collection('users'));
app.set('recipe', admin.firestore().collection('recipe'));
app.set('bucket',admin.storage().bucket())
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));


// router
app.use('/', require('./routes'));
// images
app.use(express.static('./public/images'));

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

index.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.send("test")
});

router.use('/result',require('./result'))
module.exports = router;
```

result.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

const path = require("path")
const formData = require('express-form-data');
router.use(formData.parse({uploadDir:path.join(__dirname,'upload'), autoClean:true}));
router.use(formData.format());
/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {  
  res.render('index', {
    title: "test",
  })
});

router.post('/', (req, res) => {
  console.log("aaa")
  console.log("aaa"+req.files.file1.name)
  res.redirect("/")
});
module.exports = router;
```

index.ejs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="jp">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title><%=title%></title>
</head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <fieldset class="form-group">
                <label for="file1">アップロードファイル </label>
                <input type="file" id="file1" name="file1" class="form-control" />
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset class="form-group">
                <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value=" 送信 " onclick="javascript:submitClick()" />
            </fieldset>
            <br />
        </form>
        <br />

        <script>
            function element(id) {
                return document.getElementById(id);
            }

            function submitClick() {
                const formData = new FormData(form1);
                fetch('/result', {method:"POST", body:formData})
                .then(res => res.text())
                .then(text => element('message').innerText = text)
                .catch(err => element('message').innerHTML = err.message);
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "18"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^1.4.0",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.4",
    "crypto": "^1.0.1",
    "debug": "~2.6.9",
    "dotenv": "^16.3.1",
    "ejs": "^3.1.9",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "express-form-data": "^2.0.22",
    "firebase-admin": "^11.8.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^4.3.1",
    "googleapis": "^118.0.0",
    "http-errors": "~1.6.3",
    "morgan": "~1.9.1",
    "openai": "^3.3.0",
    "util": "^0.12.5"
  }
}
```

Comment: クライアント側の問題かサーバー側の問題かぐらいは切り分けできているのでしょうか？ Fiddler などのキャプチャツールを使って要求・応答をキャプチャして、期待通り要求が出ているかなどを調べてみませんか。